# Django ORM - Get Max group by

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have three models.

Datacenter

```
class Datacenter(models.Model):
    """
    Datacenter
    """

    uuid = models.UUIDField(verbose_name=_('UUID'), unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=80, db_index=True)
    price_per_gigabyte = models.DecimalField(_('price per gigabyte'), max_digits=36, decimal_places=18, default=0, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('datacenter')
        verbose_name_plural = _('datacenters')
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} / ${self.price_per_gigabyte:.2f} per GB'
```

Server

```
class Server(models.Model):
    """
    Server
    """

    uuid = models.UUIDField(verbose_name=_('UUID'), unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    hostname = models.CharField(_('hostname'), max_length=253, db_index=True)
    datacenter = models.ForeignKey(Datacenter, models.PROTECT, related_name="servers", related_query_name="server", verbose_name=_('datacenter'))
    useful_storage_capacity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('useful storage capacity'), default=0, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('server')
        verbose_name_plural = _('servers')
        ordering = ['hostname']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

Storage

```
class Storage(models.Model):
    """
    Storage Resource
    """

    uuid = models.UUIDField(verbose_name=_('UUID'), unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    server = models.ForeignKey(Server, models.PROTECT, related_name="storages", related_query_name="storage", verbose_name=_('server'))
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, models.PROTECT, related_name="storages", related_query_name="storage", verbose_name=_('project'))
    space_used_latest_copy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('space used latest copy'), db_index=True)
    space_used_repository = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('space used repository'), db_index=True)
    space_used_other = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('space used other'), db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('storage resource')
        verbose_name_plural = _('storage resources')
        unique_together = (('server', 'project'),)
        ordering = ['server', 'project']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.uuid} ({self.project}/{self.server})'

    def get_space_used_total(self):
        return self.space_used_latest_copy + self.space_used_repository + self.space_used_other
```

Datacenter can have many servers. From storage model i can get how much space is used on server.

I need to get datacenter's most free space server (just one).

Here is what have at the moment:

```
servers = Server.objects.all() \
            .annotate(free=F('useful_storage_capacity') - Coalesce(Sum('storage__space_used_latest_copy'), V(0)) - Coalesce(Sum('storage__space_used_repository'), V(0))
                      - Coalesce(Sum('storage__space_used_other'), V(0))) \
            .filter(free__gte=space_prepaid) \
            .order_by('-free')
```

I annotate field 'free' which contains server free space. I need to group it by datacenter somehow and get max value of free. So at end i get one and the most free server from every datacenter.

Could not find any examples how to do it the right way. Whats the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Arnt you supposed to have a "storage" model somewhere, you are referring it in the query but i couldnt find any hints in code.

Comment: yes, sorry, updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`values` or `values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values) to make a GROUP BY query.

```
servers = Server.objects.all() \
            .values('datacenter__uuid', 'id') \
            .annotate(free=F('useful_storage_capacity') - Coalesce(Sum('storage__space_used_latest_copy'), V(0)) - Coalesce(Sum('storage__space_used_repository'), V(0))
                      - Coalesce(Sum('storage__space_used_other'), V(0))) \
            .annotate(max_free=Max(F('free'))
            .filter(free__gte=space_prepaid, free=F('max_free')) \
            .values('datacenter__uuid', 'id', 'free')
            .order_by('-free')
```

I think this should give you the most free server for each datacenter.  The ordering of [`.values`, `.filter`, and `.annotate` matter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#values) so this can get a bit tricky. Try using these methods.

Comment: I dont have server field in Server model. Maybe another way?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I updated it to group by the id, so it displays the free storages per server.

Comment: No, thats not what i mean. I need to group it by datacenter and get the most free server.

Comment: Could you take a look at the updated answer and give it a go? It gets a bit complicated so you may have to try your hand at using combinations and techniques with the .values, .filter and .annotate methods.

Comment: Tried pretty lookalike way like you suggested. It says: Cannot compute Max('free'): 'free' is an aggregate